# Preventing race conditions for INSERT in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, race-condition

I have a few INSERT operations in table B that are based on the value of a counter stored in table A. On each insert, I grab the value of the counter and use this `value + 1`. This value is unique across table B.

```sql
--- Pseudo code demonstrating the process. 
--- All of this occurs inside a transaction.
SELECT version FROM tableA;
INSERT INTO tableB (version, ...) VALUES (version + 1, ...);
UPDATE tableA SET version = version + 1;
```

I'm facing some issues where I sometimes have multiple concurrent INSERTs with the same value, causing all but one of the operations to fail. Is there anything that can be done to prevent this race condition from occurring? For instance, is it possible to somehow get the utmost recent value for `version`?

I've considered locking while inserting, but it feels like that could have implications on performance. Is there another way to tackle the problem?

Comment: `... causing all but one of the operations to fail.` seems to be the correct behavior (to me).

Comment: @wildplasser I've reworded my question, thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Sounds like a job for a Sequence, but it's not clear from your description when the counter is incremented: if it's unique across table B, why does table A need to be involved at all?

Comment: @IMSoP Apologies, I've updated my question to reflect the UPDATE as well. Thanks!

Comment: You could combine all three statements into one chained CTE. (this will not solve your concurrency problem, though)

Answer (score 2):

Use a [sequence](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html) instead of another table, this is the solution for 99.9% of cases. The update against the sequence is non-transactional - it will increment no matter what happens with your main `insert`.

If you want to take a value, and update it from another table then you need to make that select part of the same transaction which updates it. For this, I would do the `update` first but using the `returning into` clause to grab the new value for the version column. This is similar to the sequence method but less efficient and will provide less concurrency. It can be useful if you want to make sure the value only increments with successful inserts though.